# ¿Cómo visualizar el espectograma y reproducir correctamente un archivo de audio en formato midi mediante pygame?

Tags: pygame, midi

estoy intentando que, dado un archivo de audio en formato midi, se reproduzca y visualice su espectro de notas ( a las que quiero asignar un color) con pygame. ¿Alguien sabe que errores tengo (soy novata) ? El audio va bien en las dos primeras notas pero luego suena más rápido y acaba sonando como un disco rayado. Además los colores creo que también se asignan mal porque solo me salen verdes y azules.

```
import mido
import pygame
import pygame.midi

# Función para asignar colores a las notas
def assign_note_colors(note):
    hue = int((note / 127.0) * 360)
    color = pygame.Color(0)
    color.hsva = (hue, 100, 100, 100)
    return color

def plot_midi_notes(filename):
    pygame.init()
    pygame.midi.init()

    width, height = 800, 400
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Visualización de notas MIDI con colores')

    notes = []

    midi_file = mido.MidiFile(filename)

    for msg in midi_file:
        if msg.type in ['note_on', 'note_off']:
            notes.append((msg.note, msg.time))

    current_time = 0
    current_note = 0

    player = pygame.midi.Output(0)
    player.set_instrument(0)

    for note, duration in notes:
        current_time += duration

        start_pos = (int(current_time * 10), int(current_note * 3))
        end_pos = (int(current_time * 10), int(note * 3))

        pygame.draw.line(screen, assign_note_colors(note), start_pos, end_pos, 6)

        current_note = note

        # Reproducir la nota MIDI con la duración correcta
        player.note_on(note, 127)
        pygame.time.wait(int(duration * 1000))  # Esperar la duración en milisegundos
        player.note_off(note, 127)

        # Actualizar la ventana de pygame
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.event.wait()

    player.close()
    pygame.midi.quit()
    pygame.quit()

# Reemplazar con la ruta a tu archivo MIDI
midi_filename = "ruta/archivo.mid"

plot_midi_notes(midi_filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Nota:* no se cual sea tu objetivo con respecto al color, yo veo distintos tonos de verde y azul (no un tono). Si editas tu pregunta explicando el comportamiento esperado, tal vez pueda darte una respuesta sobre eso (tal vez no, ya que no se nada del tema sonido y apenas del tema color)

---

**Causa del error**

Al parecer, el problema es que `msg.time` representa, en resumen, el tiempo que debe transcurrir entre dos mensajes (eventos dentro del MIDI), un mensaje puede NO SER el inicio o final de una nota. Eso significa que `msg.time` no representa la duración de una nota.

Eso es lo que causaría entonces que suene rapido y como disco rayado, ya que no se está tratando el tiempo de la manera esperada.

**Propuesta**

Sin embargo, MIDI tiene varios mensajes que deberías de poder interpretar en tu programa para que suene "tal cual es".
Por suerte, resulta que estás reinventando la rueda, ya que `mido` tiene [backends](https://mido.readthedocs.io/en/stable/backends/index.html), y, sí,
ofrece un backend para pygame.midi.

Este backend hace casi todo el trabajo, solo hay que pasarle el mensaje y hacer que el programa espere el tiempo indicado.
En ese proceso, podemos detectar cuando se crea una nota y dibujar la correspondiente linea.

**Código**

A pesar de que probé casi con exito este código con un archivo mid, no se si es correcto, te recomiendo revisarlo y probarlo. Sin embargo, espero que te sirva de empujón :)

```
import mido
import pygame
import pygame.midi

def assign_note_colors(note):
    hue = int((note / 127.0) * 360)
    color = pygame.Color(0)
    color.hsva = (hue, 100, 100, 100)
    return color

pygame.init()

backend = mido.Backend('mido.backends.pygame')

current_time = 0
current_note = 0 

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

with backend.open_output() as output:
    for msg in mido.MidiFile("midi.mid"):
        # Evitamos un tipo de mensaje que no se puede
        # enviar (parece funcionar bien a pesar de esto)
        if msg.is_meta:
            continue

        pygame.time.wait(int(msg.time * 1000))

        if msg.type == "note_on":
            note = msg.note
        
            start_pos = (int(current_time * 10), int(current_note * 3))
            end_pos = (int(current_time * 10), int(note * 3))

            pygame.draw.line(screen, assign_note_colors(note), (current_time, 0), (current_time, 800))
        
            current_note = note

        current_time += msg.time

        output.send(msg)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! Con respecto al color, lo que intento es asignar a cada nota un color diferente y que al visualizarlo vea esos colores. Lo que quiero decir es que si por ejemplo escucho un audio con notas altas pues la visualización sea en tonos cálidos, y si son notas bajas salgan tonos fríos

Comment: Ya arregle lo del color:)

Comment: Me alegro! Y de nada!